# Sessions not being set on different subdomains

Tags: php, session, cookies

So I have these 2 functions in a class. One sets the session, and the other retrieves it.

```
function setCookie(){
    session_regenerate_id();
    session_set_cookie_params($expires, '/', '.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], false, true);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["example"] = "Example";
}

function getCookie(){
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION["example"])){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

For some reason, when they are set, I can only access them from the example.com domain, but when I go to the www.example.com domain, There is no session set, and the function returns false, and when I get the session cookie params, they all come up as default too. I tried removing `session_regenrate_id()` and it still only works on the example.com domain, even if I set the session through the other 'www' domain. I have 2 cookies set using the same parameters I used for the session, and I can access them no problem on either domain, but the session is just giving me problems. Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: I also tried setting the `session_name("example")` before each session start, but that didn't make a difference

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your scenario right: Do you want to access the session that was set on subdomain 1 in subdomain 2, or is your code working on subdomain 1 but the same not on subdomain 2?

Comment: I want to access the sessions throughout the site. The code works on both the domains. For example one is example.com, and the other is www.example.com The code sets the cookies, but If I login at example.com, and go to www.example.com I have to login again because it doesn't see the cookies that were set from example.com

Comment: maybe useful: [18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the cookie for all subdomains. Like you already tried. It's important that you set the correct hostname. I think that `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is not reliable.

`SERVER_NAME` is set to the host name of the virtual host. Since you use subdomains which also means vhosts the server name will not match on both subdomains.

```
function setCookie(){
    session_set_cookie_params($expires, '/', '.example.com', false, true);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["example"] = "Example";
}
```

Remember to set `$expires` somewhere. At the the moment it is not set in you code example.

Comment: You were right, Explicitly setting the domain to .example.com worked! `$expires` was set too, but it now works on the example.com domain, and www.example.com domain. Thanks!